# Selenium Grid in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run my tests in another local machine, but i always end up failing! I've seen videos implementing successfully in JAVA, but I'm trying to do it through c#.

Any Ideas are most appreciated!

```
public class Driver
{ 
    public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
        capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
        capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));


        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4446/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }
    public static void Close()
    {
        Instance.Dispose();
        Instance = null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your Selenium server is running at `http://localhost:4446/wd/hub`? I think default port is 4444, not 4446. If ports are ok, then try to change `localhost` to `http://127.0.0.1`. Info about addres is printed when you starts selenium server, example: `10:57:39.174 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use remote uri of your grid instance instead of local and ensure that you have chrome installed at least on one of your nodes. If you want to use selenium grid locally start local hub first using selenium-server-standalone.jar. You should use info from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2)
2. Also you don't need this code:

   ```
   driver = new ChromeDriver();` - you need RemoteWebDriver directly
   ```
3. For me this code works perfectly:

   ```
   var uri = 'uri_to_your_grid_hub';
   var capabilities =  new ChromeOptions().ToCapabilities();
   var commandTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
   var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(uri),capabilities,commandTimeout)
   ```