# Run Selenium Grid C# Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm implemented Nunit selenium C# testing in visual studio (Console Application n Class Library). My project in visual studio is console application. I started the selenium grid using

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="..\jar\geckodriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="..\jar\chromedriver.exe" -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="..\jar\IEDriverServer.exe" -jar ..\jar\selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

Code:

```
using Automation_Framework.Manager;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Automation_Framework.TestManager
{
    [TestFixture]
    class ChromeTestManager
    {
        private WebDriverManager webDriverManager;
        private IWebDriver driver;

        public ChromeTestManager()
        {
            webDriverManager = new WebDriverManager();
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void setup()
        {
            webDriverManager.createDriver("chrome");
            driver = webDriverManager.getDriver();
        }

        [Test]
        public void test()
        {
            driver.Url = "http://www.google.com.my";
            driver.Navigate();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void shutdown()
        {
            driver.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

I had tried execute using Test Explorer but it does not open any browser. I"m following this [tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/selenium-csharp-tutorial.html).

Questions:

1. How to run the project with browser open and see all actions?
2. How to run using Nunit-console-runner.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please help me as this is urgent.

Comment: Do you really need WebDriverManager for this? Try using only IWebDriver driver exactly like in the tutorial you followed.

Comment: @nicholas, is it only the `TestProject` that is not working as expected, is the MainProject also not "OpeningAnyBrowser" ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that:
   1. You have tried your code locally and your test is opening the browser when you run it on your machine without the grid.
   2. Your nodes are set up and registered with the hub.

You need to:
1. Use RemoteWebDriver:

```
var uri = 'uri_to_your_grid_hub';
var capabilities =  new ChromeOptions().ToCapabilities();
var commandTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(uri),capabilities,commandTimeout)
```

2. Add the attribute to a class: `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Self)]` in order to run your tests in parallel with other test classes.
3. In order to verify whether the hub is running, open the browser and navigate to http://localhost:4444 on the hub machine.

Sources:

> [How can I run NUnit(Selenium Grid) tests in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212863/how-can-i-run-nunitselenium-grid-tests-in-parallel)
>   [Selenium Grid in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38235723/selenium-grid-in-c-sharp)
>   [Useful C# WebDriver examples](https://www.gridlastic.com/csharp-webdriver-example.html)
>   [Selenium Grid set up](https://dzone.com/articles/selenium-grid-tutorial-setup-and-example-of-cross)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used grid in .Net but here my answer:

- your command is just register a hub, which needs to keep running (open a browser and test it is working)
- you need to register your **nodes** under that hub (different ports) (open a browser and test it is working)
- in your code, you should use "RemoteWebDriver" to connect to the hub. 
  something along these lines (it is in java but I hope it gives you a starting point)

  ```
  public class Gmail 
  {
     public WebDriver driver=null;    
     @Parameters("browser") //testng.xml
     @Test()
     public void GmailTest(String browser) 
     {
        System.out.println("Gmail " + browser);
        // RemoteWebdriver
        DesiredCapabilities cap = null;

        if(browser.equals("firefox")){
          cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
          cap.setBrowserName("firefox"); 
          cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
        }else if (browser.equals("iexplore")){
          cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
          cap.setBrowserName("iexplore");
          cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        }
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cap);        
        driver.get("http://gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abcd");  
        driver.quit();    
    }
  ```

I hope this helps.good luck